# Local man page sections

Tags: ubuntu, man

I'm reading a book on administration and I'm wondering whether my answers are correct related to the `man` command. I'm running Ubuntu.

> Question 1: How would you read `sync`’s local man page that was kept in
> `/usr/local/share/man`?

My answer is

```
man l sync
```

but I don't think I'm correct because it gives this output;

> No manual entry for sync in section l See 'man 7 undocumented' for
> help when manual pages are not available.

Could someone give me a better explanation of an answer to this?

Comment: What if you type `man sync`?

Comment: It shows me the page. But I doubt that's what the author referred to; this is the full question: What command would you use to read about the sync system call (not
the sync command)? How would you read sync’s local man page that was
kept in /usr/local/share/man?

- I'm interested in the difference between these 2 questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `man(1)` man page:

```
   -M path, --manpath=path
          Specify  an alternate manpath to use.  By default, man uses man‐
          path derived code to determine the path to search.  This  option
          overrides the $MANPATH environment variable and causes option -m
          to be ignored.

          A path specified as a manpath must be the root of a manual  page
          hierarchy  structured  into  sections as described in the man-db
          manual (under "The manual page system").  To view  manual  pages
          outside such hierarchies, see the -l option.
```

So, `man -M /usr/local/share/man sync`.